# missing ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash

I keep getting this error on my site in the Firebug console.  I have no idea where it's coming from, and am looking for any information on how to find it and fix.

```
missing ) after argument list
try { __flash__toXML(javascript:alert(...;()) ; } catch (e) { "<undefined/>"; }
```

Comment: Is the code in line 2 supposed to be valid code (I'm asking because it's not)?

Comment: do you need to pass a string to alert?  I'm confused about what's going in that part of the try statement...

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? Is firebug reporting a line number for the error? Could you post any code relevant to this error?

Comment: are you saying that that line of code is reported as part of the error message but doesn't appear in your own source code anywhere? Are you referencing any external libraries?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're missing a parenthesis.

Does this work?

```
try { __flash__toXML(alert()); } catch (e) { "<undefined/>"; }
```

Edit: changed the rest of the line to valid syntax

Comment: @Sime True. I wasn't sure what that line was and whether or not the ellipsis had something to do with code that was missing from an error message. It was just a guess, but I was hoping the op might be able to apply it to his original source and get somewhere with it.

Answer (score 0):

I understand this is an old post but since none of the answers above actually address the problem and this post comes up on Google searches for _*flash*_toXML, I figured let me answer this. The problem has to do with ExternalInterface not escaping the values it passes from Flash to JavaScript correctly. A description of the source of the problem and a rudimentary solution can be found at the link below:

http://mihai.bazon.net/blog/externalinterface-is-unreliable